# How to make event on localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to store some application variable (like the username and the apikey) inside angular local storage. But I wanna view my user interface change (the login button on my navbar) when I change these values. Actualy I can't catch the event when the value change.

So I have try to make a new service that is on top of the raw angular localstorage that have subject property and change property imported from rxjs. So I have this class (that is in part get from stackoverflow)

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService implements OnDestroy {
  private onSubject = new Subject<{ key: string, value: any }>();
  public changes = this.onSubject.asObservable().pipe(share());

  constructor() {
    this.start();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stop();
  }

  public getStorage() {
    let s = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      s.push({
        key: localStorage.key(i),
        value: JSON.parse(<string>localStorage.getItem(<string>localStorage.key(i)))
      });
    }
    return s;
  }

  public store(key: string, data: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    // the local application doesn't seem to catch changes to localStorage...
    this.onSubject.next({key: key, value: data})
  }

  public clear(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    // the local application doesn't seem to catch changes to localStorage...
    this.onSubject.next({key: key, value: null});
  }


  private start(): void {
    window.addEventListener("storage", this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
  }

  private storageEventListener(event: StorageEvent) {
    if (event.storageArea == localStorage) {
      let v;
      try {
        if (event.newValue !== null) {
          v = JSON.parse(event.newValue);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        v = event.newValue;
      }
      // @ts-ignore
      this.onSubject.next({key: event.key, value: v});
    }
  }

  private stop(): void {
    window.removeEventListener("storage", this.storageEventListener.bind(this));
    this.onSubject.complete();
  }
}
```

in my login component I have this :

```js
      const storageService = new StorageService()
      if (res.status === 200) {
        storageService.store('logged',JSON.stringify(await res.json()))
        this.redirectAfterLogin()
      }else {
        storageService.clear('logged')
      }
```

and in my navbarr component I have try this :

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('storage',function (param){
      console.log('here ? key is :'+param.key)
    })
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The event isn't called because I can't see console.log when I edit localStorage data